# Where to keep and how to handle the version of a Java application?

Tags: java, version, java-11

I am working on a Java application and want to show the version number as part of an "About" or "Help" dialog.

**UPDATE**: As a clarification: I do not want to display the Java version but the version of the application.

At the moment I keep the current version information in the `build.gradle` and ideally, I do not need to keep track of the version in different places for runtime and while building.

I found some very old articles which suggested to get the current version from the JAR`s manifest but I am not sure if this is still the way to go.

My natural approach would be to have an `application.properties` file in the classpath which contains entries like `application.name`, and `application.version`. If I am not wrong those properties can be accessed by Gradle while building the distribution and as well by the application during runtime.

Are there any other ways to do such a thing I am not aware of?

Comment: *version number as part* ... do you mean Java version? and does something fail with your current approach?

Comment: @nullpointer Sorry, I was not too clear: I am talking about the version of the application I develop.

Answer (score 1):

`System.getProperty("java.version")` should do it – provided you are looking for the Java version.

If you are looking for the application's version instead, you can propagate that to the application's `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and read it from there.